# Port 443 "listening" but "not open"

Tags: ssl, centos6

I am running Apache/2.2.15 on Centos 6.6.

I have a Verizon router and checked the port forwarding and saw

```
    WorkstationName 192.168.1.6 HTTPS TCP Any -> 443    All Broadband Devices   Active
```

I went to the command line and entered

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

I also entered

```
sudo netstat -anltp | grep LISTEN
```

and got

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1462/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2297/sshd           
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      2340/httpd          
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      2340/httpd          
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2297/sshd
```

However, when I enter my website name (which works fine with http) as follows

```
https://websitename.com
```

it just hangs.  I then go to http://www.mynetworktest.com/ports.php and click on

Test https - Port 443

and get

```
Port 443 is not open on my.ip.addre.ess

sudo iptables -L -n
```

gives

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.1          0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.1          0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  151.198.0.38         0.0.0.0/0           tcp     flags:!0x17/0x02 
ACCEPT     udp  --  151.198.0.38         0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            255.255.255.255     
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.255       
DROP       all  --  224.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/8         
DROP       all  --  255.255.255.255      0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0             
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
LSI        all  -f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/min burst 5 
INBOUND    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LOG_FILTER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0     level 6 prefix `Unknown Input' 
DROP       all  --  69.84.207.246        0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  69.84.207.246        0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 
LOG_FILTER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Unknown Forward' 

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.4          192.168.1.1         tcp dpt:53 
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.4          192.168.1.1         udp dpt:53 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.4          151.198.0.38        tcp dpt:53 
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.4          151.198.0.38        udp dpt:53 
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  224.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/8         
DROP       all  --  255.255.255.255      0.0.0.0/0           
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0             
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
OUTBOUND   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LOG_FILTER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0     level 6 prefix `Unknown Output' 
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            69.84.207.246       
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            69.84.207.246       
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 

Chain INBOUND (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
LSI        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LOG_FILTER (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain LSI (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG_FILTER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Inbound ' 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x02 
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x04 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Inbound ' 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x17/0x04 
LOG        icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Inbound ' 
DROP       icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg     5/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Inbound ' 
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LSO (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG_FILTER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg     5/sec burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix `Outbound ' 
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain OUTBOUND (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: @krisFR but it "works fine with HTTP" which is also listening on IPv6. OtagoHarbour - temporarily turn IPtables off, see if it makes a difference. Can you load HTTPS sites from the local computer?

Comment: Please provide the output of `iptables -L -n --lines`.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I'm tired...deleted :)

Comment: I can load other https site from a local computer.

Comment: Turning off IP tables opens port 443

Comment: What if you add `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` ?

Comment: @krisFR.  That worked!!!  I don't understand why it didn't work when I used -A instead of -I.  I guess it is the order it appears in the table.  Thanks very much for your help,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact is that you added the rule that allows port 443 at the end of the `INPUT` chain.

But you have a previous rule that drops everything :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
[...]
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0
[...]
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
[...]
```

With `iptables` rules order matters!

Use `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` to put the rule at the beginning of your `INPUT` chain.

The `-A` flag (Append) adds the rule at the end of the specified chain, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

You added the rules for port 443 at the end of the INPUT chain.  Rule #13 (as listed above) drops any traffic that did not match against an earlier rule.

Use the `-I` flag when adding the rule instead of `-A`.  For example:

```
  sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

That way the traffic will not be dropped.